# Ansible Errors in openshift-ansible/playbooks/byo/config.yml

Tags: ansible, openshift-origin

I am unable to run

```
ansible-playbook openshift-ansible/playbooks/byo/config.yml
```

as I get various errors depending on the verison of ansible used.  On various 1.9.x versions, the error is

```
ERROR: fail is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
```

and on 2.0.0:

```
ERROR! 'vars_files' is not a valid attribute for a PlaybookInclude

The error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/openshift-ansible/playbooks/byo/openshift-cluster/config.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- include: ../../common/openshift-cluster/config.yml
  ^ here
```

I have seen this error reported on github, with the 1.9 solution supposedly addressed by moving to 2.0, and the 2.0 error mentioned as being fixed with a 1.9 downgrade, but cannot find a set up in which it actually does work and would appreciate some tip as this seems like one of those steps that should go easily.

This is on RHEL 7 with docker version:

```
[root@mtl-vm374 ansible]# docker --version
Docker version 1.8.2-el7.centos, build a01dc02/1.8.2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a bug in [openshift-ansible](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible) that you should report upstream.  Alternatively, if you'd like to fix it yourself, we'll need to look through the playbook.

Comment: did you follow the advanced installation? The OpenShift playbook uses your ansible/host file. So maybe something wrong in there?

Comment: I did try the advanced, but I won't claim to know I did it correctly.  Github mentions this as a bug with workarounds involving changing version and deploy_helper.py that do not work.

My ansible/hosts file is:

`[OSv3:children]
masters
nodes

# Set variables common for all OSEv3 hosts
[OSv3:vars]
# SSH user, this user should allow ssh based auth without requiring a password
ansible_ssh_user=root

# If ansible_ssh_user is not root, ansible_sudo must be set to true
#ansible_sudo=true

deployment_type=origin

# host group for masters
[masters]
jak-vm374

# host group for nodes
[nodes]
jak-vm374`

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few 1.9.4 Ansible versions, I finally found an install that works:
    http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/a/ansible1.9-1.9.4-2.el7.noarch.rpm

--John